# Laravel unique data format fetch

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to fetch the records from database with unique created_at fields.

Ex.

```
id: 1
created_at: 2018-04-20 17:39:04

id: 2
created_at: 2018-04-20 21:39:04

id: 3 
created_at: 2018-04-21 17:39:04
```

Now, I need to get 2 records with single query. Why I am referring  2 - one for 2018-04-20 and one for 2018-04-21

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy`

```
DB::table('table_name')
            ->groupBy('created_at')
            ->get();
```

or if you are looking for group by only by Date you can use

```
DB::table('table_name')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
            ->get();
```

check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: But there is an issue with this, I . need to get the results based on 'Y-m-d' and the above is giving me 3 results. Rather there should be results.

Answer (score 0):

To select distinct data based on created_at
1. select distinct(created_at) from tableName

And if u want only two records then use limit 2 at the end of the query

2. select distinct(created_at) from tableName limit 2

Comment: But there is an issue with this, I need to get the results based on 'Y-m-d' and the above is giving me 3 results. Rather there should be results.

Answer (score 0):

```
      DB::table('table_name')
        ->select('*' ,DB::raw(' DISTINCT (created_at) ') )
        ->get();
```

You can use `DISTINCT()` for fetching the unique entries.

Comment: But there is an issue with this, I need to get the results based on 'Y-m-d' and the above is giving me 3 results. Rather there should be results.